# Почему не работает вывод вложенного объекта в react с помощью map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map

Пытаюсь вывести данные из вложенного объекта с помощью метода map, не понимаю в чем ошибка. Терминал выдает "Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," ".

Вот код компонента:

```
import React from 'react';
import VacancyCategory from '../VacancyCategory/VacancyCategory';
import DATA from '../../data/data';

const Main = () => {

  return (

    <div>
      {DATA.map(({id, name, vacancy_list}) => (
        {vacancy_list.map((data) => (

        <VacancyCategory
          name={data.name}
          salary={data.salary}
          tag_list={data.tag_list}
          key={data.id}
        />
        ))}
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Сами данные:

```
   const DATA = [
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Информационные технологии",
    "vacancy_list": [
      {
        "id": 345,
        "name": "Системный администратор IT",
        "salary": 80000,
        "tag_list": ["Информационные технологии"]
      },
      {
        "id": 50,
        "name": "Системный администратор службы поддержки клиентов",
        "salary": 70000,
        "tag_list": ["Информационные технологии"]
      },
```

Comment: Что за ошибка? И что такое **i.name** в методе map, есои элемен в переменной data?

Comment: Да, не тот код добавлен был. Ошибка в терминале: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","  на строке с  " {vacancy_list.map((data) => (  "

Comment: Больше похоже на то, что у вас кривой JSON. Ошибка говорит о том, что синтаксис не верный.

Comment: `=> ({vacancy_list.map((data) => (` здесь ошибка синтаксиса. Внутри круглых скобок `{}` отвечает за литерал объекта, а не за блок кода, поэтому и получаешь ошибку

Comment: @SwaD, тут нет json, просто ошибка синтаксиса в самом коде

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Весьма распространенная ошибка. Работая с map следите, что бы возвращался один элемент.

```
<div>
  {DATA.map(({id, name, vacancy_list}) => (
   <div>
    {vacancy_list.map((data) => (
     <VacancyCategory
       name={data.name}
        salary={data.salary}
      tag_list={data.tag_list}
       key={data.id}
     />
    ))}
  </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, заработало!